# jquery hover and click conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click

i'm doing active, hover, unhover for logos using jQuery. I know that there is better way, doing it using css, but i need to use jQuery, because the logos are generated in php.

So, here is html.

```
<li>
   <input type="radio" name="payment_system" id="YANDEXMONEY" value="YANDEXMONEY">
   <label for="YANDEXMONEY"><img class="payment-system-img" src="images/icons/icon-ym.png" /></label>
   <div id="ym-price" class="price"><span>500</span> руб.</div>
</li>
```

To make it active

```
$('.payment-system-img').click(function() {
    makeAllInactive();
    makeActive($(this));
});
```

functions used

```
function makeAllInactive() {
    $('.payment-system-img').each(function() {
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

        if(imgSrc.indexOf('-hover') != -1) {
            var src = imgSrc.replace('-hover', '');
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }
    });
}

function makeActive(img) {
    var imgSrc = img.attr('src').split('.');

    if(imgSrc[0].indexOf('-hover') == -1) {
        img.attr('src', imgSrc[0] + '-hover.' + imgSrc[1]);
    }
}
```

making it active on hover and inactive on unhover.

```
$('.payment-system-img').hover(
    function() {
        makeActive($(this));
    },
    function() {
        makeInactive($(this));
    }
);
```

function used

```
function makeInactive(img) {
    var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

    if(imgSrc.indexOf('-hover') != -1) {
        var src = imgSrc.replace('-hover', '');
        img.attr('src', src);
    }
}
```

And here comes the conflict. When i click on image it comes active, but when im unhovering it after click, it comes inactive because hover function. How to do it right way using jQuery, without conflicts? thanks.

Comment: So, you basically want it to stay active after a click, even if unhovered?

Comment: `but i need to use jQuery, because the logos are generated in php` Could you elebaorate on this?

Comment: @A.Wolff Why? It doesn't matter very much, if PHP wasn't mentioned, I don't think it would make a big difference, as the problem is not with the PHP/jQuery, but with the way it is written..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class when an item has been selected:

```
$('.payment-system-img').click(function() {
    makeAllInactive();
    makeActive($(this).addClass('selected'));
});
```

Then, in the `makeInactive()` function you check the class first and skip it when the class is present:

```
function makeInactive(img) {
    if (img.hasClass('selected')) { return; }
    var imgSrc = img.attr('src');

        if(imgSrc.indexOf('-hover') != -1) {
            var src = imgSrc.replace('-hover', '');
            img.attr('src', src);
        }
    }
```

Lastly, inside the `makeAllInactive()` you need to remove it:

```
function makeAllInactive() 
{
    $('.payment-system-img')
        .removeClass('selected')
        .each(function() {
            var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

            if(imgSrc.indexOf('-hover') != -1) {
                var src = imgSrc.replace('-hover', '');
                $(this).attr('src', src);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a global variable to track the state of clicking/hovering/stuffs,

```
var clicked = 0;

$('.payment-system-img').click(function() {
    clicked = !clicked; // just flips the state, 
                        // so upon re-clicking, 
                        // default behaviour resumes.
    makeAllInactive();
    makeActive($(this));
});

$('.payment-system-img').hover(
        function() {
            makeActive($(this));
        },
        function() {
            if (!clicked) {
                makeInactive($(this));
            }
        }
    );
```